# NVM - Set Node Version On Terminal Opening

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

I'm using node with NVM, but I need to: `nvm use 4.0` every time I open the terminal.

So I changed my `.bashrc` to this:

```
nvm use 4.0
```

But it's not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you put an `echo dot bashrc` command in your `.bashrc`? Is it executed? I have `nvm use 4` in my `.profile` and that works fine.

Comment: Then it seems your `.bashrc` is not run when you open the terminal. Try putting `nvm use 4.0` in `.profile` instead.

Comment: have you checked that it's in your $PATH. try running with the complete path /usr/whatever/nvm use 4.0